# Can't use Javascript in 2 places?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code in my header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ShowTimes() {
  var now = new Date();
  var hrs = 23-now.getHours();
  var mins = 59-now.getMinutes();
  var secs = 59-now.getSeconds();
  var str = '';
      str += '<b><span style="color:#FF9600;">Discount Ending:</span> <span style="color:#489FDC;">'+hrs+' Hours '+mins+' Minutes '+secs+' Seconds</span></b>';
  document.getElementById('countdownToMidnight').innerHTML = str;
}
var _cntDown;
function StopTimes() {
    clearInterval(_cntDown);
}

</script>
```

And I added this to my body tag:

```
<body id="homepage" onload="_cntDown=setInterval('ShowTimes()',1000)">
```

Then I simply add this wherever I want my countdown time to display:

```
<div id="countdownToMidnight"></div>
```

The problem is that if I put `<div id="countdownToMidnight"></div>` in 2 places on the page, only the second place shows up.  Is there something I'm doing wrong in the code that would cause that to happen?

Comment: thats because ID's should be unique

Comment: because id is unique and the latest place u have declared only be taken into effect.

Comment: if you want to do this in multiple places, use the `class=` attribute

Comment: And please don't eval the function in the interval!

Answer (score 1):

`ID` should be unique, try using `class` instead, like:

```
<div class="countdownToMidnight"></div>
```

and js change:

```
document.getElementById('countdownToMidnight').innerHTML = str;
```

to

```
var divEle = document.getElementsByClassName('countdownToMidnight');
for(var d = 0,len = divEle.length; d < len; d++) {
   divEle[d].innerHTML = str;
}
```